# update child views without changing activity's orientation

Tags: android

I have an activity who's orientation is locked to portrait:

```
    <activity android:name="MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
```

However within the activity i have a few custom views in which I draw some text, rectangles and notably, a Path representing an arrow.

I need to be able to update the arrow when the phone is rotated, without changing the overall layout of the activity.

so the activity and layout is always portrait, but my nested views need to be notified and re-drawn when the phone is tilted from portrait to landscape.

How can I listen for the change in physical orientation and update tell my nested views to redraw?

thanks, p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**:

It looks like there is no way to detect orientation change when current active `Activity` has `screenOrientation` set to `portrait` or `landscape` (haven't tested other values though. Even using broadcast receiver and [ACTION_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED).

The only way I can think of, is to manually track sensors.

---

**This is not working:**

You should override [`onConfigurationChanged()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged%28android.content.res.Configuration%29) function in your `Activity` and refresh your UI from that function.

Note that you need to add `android:configChanges="orientation"` to you activity in order for this function to be called.

Comment: I have added both the xml attribute and the method implementation (which should show a Toast when called) and nothing happens. i'm guessing that's because of the `screenOrientation="portrait"` setting?

Comment: @inazaruk - Have you tried this with screenOrientation locked in the manifest, because I just did, and onConfigurationChanged wasn't called at all

Comment: You're right. If `screenOrientation` is set, screen orientation configuration changes will not be reported.

Comment: So is there another approach?

Comment: Nope, it looks like `screenOrientation` is handled somewhere deep inside the system, because even registering broadcast receiver for ACTION_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED event doesn't help.

Comment: Thanks, looks like I'll have to change the orientation of the activity then :(

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can! Just subclass `OrientationEventListener` and do what you need to do in the `onOrientationChanged` method.

When you instantiate your class, obviously pass context to the constructor and then call `enable()` on the object and you're good to go.

The only downside is that it isn't just PORTRAIT or LANDSCAPE, but instead the exact rotation in degrees. But with a little debugging and a nifty if/then statement you can figure out the ranges of those numbers.

Here's a helpful hint from the docs:

> Called when the orientation of the device has changed. `orientation`
> parameter is in degrees, ranging from 0 to 359. `orientation` is 0
> degrees when the device is oriented in its natural position, 90
> degrees when its left side is at the top, 180 degrees when it is
> upside down, and 270 degrees when its right side is to the top.
> `ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN` is returned when the device is close to flat and
> the orientation cannot be determined.

The docs can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationEventListener.html).

Comment: Also, even though this is a later reply, I thought it'd still be helpful for someone if they needed it from this point on.